# Issue with switching / clicking an iFrame jmeter selenium

Tags: jmeter, web

[image]

As on the image I have to click on the highlighted iFrame and I'm on `Jmeter Web Driver Sampler`.
The issue is the bottom part of the iFrame id will get change time to time.
So can't exactly identify it using ID.

> If this is with C# then I can get a list with all tag names == iFrame
> and click on the selected iFrame.

But with Jmeter Web Driver Sampler I'm not sure how to do something like this.

Answer (score 2):

I can see 2 iframes in your picture, one is visible and another one is not visible (the highlighted one).

So you need to:

1. Locate the [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) element which [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property is not `none` using normal [WebDriver.findElement()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) function which returns a [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)
2. [Switch to it using the WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/#using-a-webelement) from the previous step

Example code:

```
var iframe = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//iframe[not(contains(@style, 'display: none'))]")
WDS.browser.switchTo().frame(iframe)
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: I just click on the iframe by this xpath code. //*[contains(@id="container-")]